# how to get rid of Object #<Object> has no method 'push' error?

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

Hi i am trying to push data on to JSON object which has key already defined but i am still getting uncaught typeError at line where  i have alert("3") and alert("6")

```
 server.on('update_message_from_server', function(data){
                if(data.message_to!=false){
                    alert("1");
                    if(data.message_from==<?php echo $session_user_id;?>){
                        alert("2");
                        if(message_store.hasOwnProperty(data.message_to_email)){
                            alert("3");
                            message_store[data.message_to_email].push((data));
                            str2 = '<div id ="recent_message_log_entry'+data.message_to_email+'"><div>'+data.message+'</div><div>'+data.date_posted+'</div></div>';
                            $(document.getElementById("recent_message_log_entry"+data.message_to_email)).replaceWith(str2);
                        }else{
                            alert("4");
                            message_store[data.message_to_email]= new Array();
                            message_store[data.message_to_email]=data;
                            string = '<div><div>'+data.message_to_email+'</div><div>'+data.message+'</div><div>'+data.date_posted+'</div></div>';
                            $("#new_updates").append(string);
                        }
                    }else{
                        alert("5");
                        if(message_store.hasOwnProperty(data.message_from_email)){
                            alert("6");
                            message_store[data.message_from_email].push((data));
                            str2 = '<div id ="recent_message_log_entry'+data.message_from_email+'"><div>'+data.message+'</div><div>'+data.date_posted+'</div></div>';
                            $(document.getElementById("recent_message_log_entry"+data.message_from_email)).replaceWith(str2);
                        }else{
                            alert("7");
                            message_store[data.message_from_email]= new Array();
                            message_store[data.message_from_email]=data;
                            string = '<div><div>'+data.message_from_email+'</div><div>'+data.message+'</div><div>'+data.date_posted+'</div></div>';
                            $("#new_updates").append(string);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("8");
                    alert("Email Does not exist "+data.message_to_email);
                }
                alert(JSON.stringify(message_store));
            });
```

How do i rectify this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `message_store[data.message_from_email]` is not defined, you are first assigning an empty array to it, then instead of pushing data to the array to are overwriting the array with `data`

The bug is in the line

```
message_store[data.message_from_email]= new Array();
message_store[data.message_from_email]=data;
```

it should be

```
message_store[data.message_from_email] = new Array();
message_store[data.message_from_email].push(data);
```

or shorten

```
message_store[data.message_from_email]= [data];
```

So

```
server.on('update_message_from_server', function(data){
    if(data.message_to!=false){
        alert("1");
        if(data.message_from==<?php echo $session_user_id;?>){
            alert("2");
            if(message_store.hasOwnProperty(data.message_to_email)){
                alert("3");
                message_store[data.message_to_email].push((data));
                str2 = '<div id ="recent_message_log_entry'+data.message_to_email+'"><div>'+data.message+'</div><div>'+data.date_posted+'</div></div>';
                $(document.getElementById("recent_message_log_entry"+data.message_to_email)).replaceWith(str2);
            }else{
                alert("4");
                message_store[data.message_from_email]=[data];
                string = '<div><div>'+data.message_to_email+'</div><div>'+data.message+'</div><div>'+data.date_posted+'</div></div>';
                $("#new_updates").append(string);
            }
        }else{
            alert("5");
            if(message_store.hasOwnProperty(data.message_from_email)){
                alert("6");
                message_store[data.message_from_email].push((data));
                str2 = '<div id ="recent_message_log_entry'+data.message_from_email+'"><div>'+data.message+'</div><div>'+data.date_posted+'</div></div>';
                $(document.getElementById("recent_message_log_entry"+data.message_from_email)).replaceWith(str2);
            }else{
                alert("7");
                message_store[data.message_from_email]=[data];
                string = '<div><div>'+data.message_from_email+'</div><div>'+data.message+'</div><div>'+data.date_posted+'</div></div>';
                $("#new_updates").append(string);
            }
        }
    }else{
        alert("8");
        alert("Email Does not exist "+data.message_to_email);
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(message_store));
});
```